# Changable amount of scanned numbers per line (scanf)

Tags: c, scanf, ansi-c

I need to scan a changable amount of numbers separated by space like

for example dim=3

```
void scanNumbers(int dim)
{
    // scans dim amount of numbers like "5235435 656435 23423423"
}
```

Is there a short way to do it, like  scanf("<%d * dim>", n1, n2, ... to dim)or I have to write a function that reads each character in loop?

I tried

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
int *Data = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int) * (n+1));

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    scanf("%d ", &Data[i]);
```

But it waits for one more number to finish scanning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf("%d ", &Data[i]);` waits for 1 more number because the following `" "` in the format directs `scanf()` to continue scanning until non-white space is encountered after the number.

---

The key problem is that `"%d"` reads leading white-space first before scanning in an `int`.  It does **not** distinguish between `' '` and `'\n'` which is critical when reading per *line* with `scanf()`

The best method is to read a *line* into a buffer with `fgets()` and then 
parse the `int` using `strtol()` or `sscanf()`.

```
int n;
scanf("%d%*1c", &n);
int Data[n];
char buffer[40*n];
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);

// parsing with sscanf() using %n to determine scanning length
int i;
char *p = buffer;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  int offset;
  if (sscanf(p, "%d %n", &Data[i], &offset) != 1) {
    break;
  }
  p += offset;
}

// use Data[0] ... Data[i-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no *short* way to scan a variable number of inputs in a single call to `scanf()`, but it is rather easy to write a `for` loop that scans one number at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Based in your info, I can say that you have two options. If you don't know the number of your input, use `strtol()`, with this you will tell your users what to use as a delimiter `;,` or a space. If you do know how many inputs the program will receive, use `fgets()` to save line to a buffer followed by `sscanf()` to parse.